# Text classification (Bag of words) using Keras wrong predictions && model creating non existent classes

Tags: python, text, keras, classification

Trying to build a prediction model for text classification model using bag of words. I have followed various guides and information to build the below methodology.

Training data set has about 1.3 million records with item descriptions and their associated departments. There are 54 departments which is my number of classes.

**Issue**

```
test_dataset = ['white puppy','cottonelle clean  mega','zagg universal keyboard','sweet milk tea'']
```

The issue is during prediction of the above array which has exactly the same items as my training dataset. They either land in wrong buckets or there is an entirely new class getting created which does not exist in my dataset. My class range is between (min 1 & max 98) but in total there are 54 classes.

**example:**
sweet milk tea should go to 1 but goes to 2
cottonelle clean  mega should go to 3 but goes to 45 which does not even exist.

**Here are my input datasets:**
text_train
text_test
label_train
label_test

**Parameters**

```
vocab_size = 130000
longest_string = 20
hidden_size = 128
num_classes = 54
batch_size = 25000
epochs =7
```

**Converting label data into one-hot vectors:**

```
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
x = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(label_train)
label_cat_train = np_utils.to_categorical(x, num_classes= num_classes)
y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(label_test)
label_cat_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes= num_classes)
```

**Converting my text data into numerical arrays and padding**

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text_train)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text_train)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=longest_string)
```

**Building the model and training the data**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, hidden_size,input_length=longest_string))
model.add(GRU(256, dropout=0.25, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(256, dropout=0.25))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, label_cat_train, validation_split=0.1, epochs=epochs,batch_size = batch_size)
```

Also from the output model performance is pretty high as well. This does not make sense.

```
2018-09-18 22:05:41.039445: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 668s 606us/step - loss: 3.4749 - acc: 0.1313 - val_loss: 2.6991 - val_acc: 0.2888
Epoch 2/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 673s 611us/step - loss: 2.0425 - acc: 0.4523 - val_loss: 1.3667 - val_acc: 0.6435
Epoch 3/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 682s 620us/step - loss: 1.0634 - acc: 0.7231 - val_loss: 0.8052 - val_acc: 0.7945
Epoch 4/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 679s 617us/step - loss: 0.6992 - acc: 0.8187 - val_loss: 0.6251 - val_acc: 0.8392
Epoch 5/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 679s 617us/step - loss: 0.5478 - acc: 0.8562 - val_loss: 0.5329 - val_acc: 0.8616
Epoch 6/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 677s 615us/step - loss: 0.4618 - acc: 0.8770 - val_loss: 0.4814 - val_acc: 0.8739
Epoch 7/7
1101365/1101365 [==============================] - 690s 626us/step - loss: 0.4064 - acc: 0.8903 - val_loss: 0.4411 - val_acc: 0.8840
```

HIghly appreciate if someone can provide inputs on this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue lies in your label encoding. You need to use the very same encoder in order for your labels to match:

```
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
x = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(label_train)
label_cat_train = np_utils.to_categorical(x, num_classes=num_classes)
y = labelencoder_Y.transform(label_test)  # do not fit again, but reuse the encoder
label_cat_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=num_classes)
```

Perhaps you also need to check your category labels. Above, you write that

> mega should go to 3 but goes to 45 which does not even exist

but state that

```
num_classes = 54
```

which is also the size of your output layer.

Comment: The 'test_dataset' does not undergo any transformation by the encoder. As a matter of fact this is how it is transformed using the tokenizer.

`sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_dataset)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)
test_data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=longest_string)`

I have updated the info about the classes in the OP.

Comment: Please have a close look at the code that I posted. You are using `labelencoder_Y` to encode the test labels (as you should), but in your version you are effectively instantiating a new encoder for the test labels, potentially resulting in a different numeric label being assigned to a class.

Comment: Tried the below but the result is same. Am I still missing something?

`labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
x = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(label_train)
label_cat_train = np_utils.to_categorical(x, num_classes=num_classes)

test_dataset = ['white puppy','cottonelle clean  mega','zagg universal keyboard','sweet milk tea'']

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_dataset)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)
test_data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=longest_string)
predictions = model.predict_classes(test_data)`

Comment: Have you evaluated your model on the training data? Have you inspected single predictions to see what is going wrong?

Comment: After some investigation the model is predicting correct but the output is somehow transformed to a number between 1 and 54.

I have applied some post transformation to match up the predictions. 
`blend['predicted_dept'] = blend['predicted_dept'].replace({53:98,52:97,51:96,50:95,49:94,48:93,.................,10:11,9:10,8:9,7:8,6:7,5:6,4:5,
3:4,2:3,1:2,0:1})

This is not an ideal solution but it works.

Comment: Your output layer still has 54 neurons, one for each of the 54 classes, right? So `np.argmax(model.predict(x))` gives you a an index between 0 and 53. Does that clear things up?